# Returning `typeof` with Generics

Tags: typescript

In typescript, how can I return a subclass of a super class that uses generics?

Here's what I was hoping would work:

```
interface SuperProps {}

class SuperComponent<P extends SuperProps> extends React.Component<P> { }

interface SubProps extends SuperProps {}

class SubComponent extends SuperComponent<SubProps> { }

function get(): typeof SuperComponent {
    return SubComponent;
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
error TS2322: Type 'typeof SubComponent' is not assignable to type 'typeof SuperComponent'.
  Type 'SubComponent' is not assignable to type 'SuperComponent<P>'.
    Types of property 'props' are incompatible.
      Type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<SubProps>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<P>'.
        Type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<SubProps>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<P>'.
```

This is basically saying that SubProps != P, right? How can I do this?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with just the code you provided.

Comment: [here is the code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=namespace%20React%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20Component%3CP%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20readonly%20props%3A%20P%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20SuperProps%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Aclass%20SuperComponent%3CP%20extends%20SuperProps%3E%20extends%20React.Component%3CP%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20SubProps%20extends%20SuperProps%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aclass%20SubComponent%20extends%20SuperComponent%3CSubProps%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Afunction%20get()%3A%20typeof%20SuperComponent%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20SubComponent%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: but with real React, the error appears in the IDE only, command-line compilation is fine, and the error disappears in the IDE after adding `import * as React from 'react';` at the top.

Comment: hmm, I see the same error when compiling on the command line.

Comment: My guess is that we are using different versions of React typings, and mine has well-hidden `any` somewhere...

Comment: ah, yeah! updateing @types/react fixed it. thanks!